# Add attribute to product box on category page in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

I would like to show base prices for all products (variable + fixed) on the category page of my WooCommerce store. Germanized offers the shortcode `[gzd_product_unit_price]` to add the prices, but I can't find the option to add the shortcode in the WooCommerce standard customizer. Is there an option to add an additional checkbox for the base price in the page customizer (see screenshot) or a `woocommerce_action` PHP snippet I could add?

[image: mm]

Comment: Default customizer dont have option like this. That is more theme related if its included as option. Contact theme author or modify theme customizer to your needs.

Comment: Where/how can I edit the theme to add options in the customizer the client could use themself?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API